# Svelte seeing the wrong values render between pages for a re-used component

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I imagine I must have something wrong in the reactivity here.

I have a route setup like so: `/src/routes/[year]/+page.svelte`

The +page.ts file loads data from a JSON file stored in the repo. It uses the year parameter to determine which data to load.

The Data is then passed to a couple instances of this component:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import type { Prediction } from '$lib/types/prediction'
  import type { IconDetails } from '$lib/types/iconDetails'
  import { Score } from '$lib/types/score'
  import Icon from './icons/Icon.svelte'

  export let prediction: Prediction
  export let isCoolRanch = false
  export let index: number

  const descriptions = {
    [Score.Correct]: 'Correct prediction',
    [Score.Incorrect]: 'Incorrect prediction',
    [Score.Partial]: 'Partially correct prediction'
  }

  const iconNames = {
    [Score.Correct]: 'done',
    [Score.Incorrect]: 'close',
    [Score.Partial]: 'clock'
  }

  const iconColors = {
    [Score.Correct]: '#0a0',
    [Score.Incorrect]: '#a00',
    [Score.Partial]: '#aa0'
  }

  const crIcoNColors = {
    [Score.Correct]: '#0f0',
    [Score.Incorrect]: '#f00',
    [Score.Partial]: '#ff0'
  }

  let description = ''
  let iconName: keyof IconDetails | null = null
  let iconColor: string = ''

  function setIconDetails() {
    if (prediction.score === null) {
      description = ''
      iconColor = ''
      iconName = null
    } else {
      description = descriptions[prediction.score]
      iconName = iconNames[prediction.score] as keyof IconDetails
      iconColor = isCoolRanch ? crIcoNColors[prediction.score] : iconColors[prediction.score]
    }
  }

  // whenever prediction changes, update the variables
  $: prediction, setIconDetails()
</script>

<li>
  <div class="itemContents">
    <div class="iconWrapper">
      {#if iconName}
        <Icon
          name={iconName}
          fill={iconColor}
          ariaLabel={description}
          includeShadow={isCoolRanch}
        />
      {:else}
        {index + 1}.&nbsp;
      {/if}
    </div>
    {prediction.prediction}
  </div>
</li>

<style>
  li .itemContents {
    display: flex;
  }
</style>
```

Regardless of which page I go to, the first one always renders correctly. The right text shows, as well as the icon & colour of the icon. However when i click through to other years for the page, sometimes icon colours will be wrong, or the wrong icon will display, or both.

I tried using `$: prediction.score, setIconDetails()` as well since that's the main value im looking for, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most valid question on my part. Looking at the pages more closely, i noticed the icon color was always right, but the icon itself was not. The issue was with reactivity in the Icon component which i didn't share. I had to define the icon variable here as a reactive statement:

```
  const icons: IconDetails = {
    close: {
      name: 'close',
      svg: `<path d="m256-200-56-56 224-224-224-224 56-56 224 224 224-224 56 56-224 224 224 224-56 56-224-224-224 224Z" />`
    },
    done: {
      name: 'done',
      svg: `<path d="M382-240 154-468l57-57 171 171 367-367 57 57-424 424Z" />`
    },
    clock: {
      name: 'clock',
      svg: `<path d="M480-80q-83 0-156-31.5T197-197q-54-54-85.5-127T80-480q0-83 31.5-156T197-763q54-54 127-85.5T480-880q83 0 156 31.5T763-763q54 54 85.5 127T880-480q0 83-31.5 156T763-197q-54 54-127 85.5T480-80ZM253-253l227-227v-320q-134 0-227 93t-93 227q0 64 24 123t69 104Z"/>`
    }
  }

  let icon: IconData
  $: icon = icons[name]
```